# LDAP Operations error 1 in PHP across trusted domains

Tags: php, ldap

I have an AD forest in which I have multiple domains. There is one parent domain and the others are child domains. The trust relationship is bidirectional. I want to fetch user data from the AD. I connected to the root domain controller and performed a bind with a service account residing in one of the child domains. I am able to do that successfully. I get an Operations Error when I try to search for users in the AD without much detail as to why the error arose.

My Code:

```
$ldap_server_url = "<LDAP Server URL>";
$ldap_bind_dn = "<Service Account Credentials>";
$ldap_bind_dn_password = "<Service Account Password>";

$ldap_search_base = "dc=parentdomain,dc=com";
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldap_server_url); 
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0 ) {
    ldap_set_option(null, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 5);
}

ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$ldap_bind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldap_bind_dn, $ldap_bind_password);

$attrs = array("ou", "sn", "givenname", "mail");
if($ldap_bind){
    $search_filter = "(&(objectClass=*)(cn=myuser))";
    $search_result = ldap_search($ldapconn, $ldap_search_base, $search_filter, $attrs);
    echo ldap_errno($ldapconn);
    echo ldap_error($ldapconn);

}
```

Is it something to do with permissions?

Comment: Have you tried setting ```LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS``` to ```1```?

Comment: yes. it also gives the same error

Comment: Do you use a sAMAccountName as Service credentials or a full DN? It seems that using a DN might be better according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742751/ldap-operations-error

Comment: I tried with the DN and it still does not work. I am running this piece of code on an IIS Server running PHP. Is it something to do with that?