# ldap_search() Bad search filter : memberof

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Through LDAP I am trying to get te e-mail adresses of all users in a group. Below is the code I've got and I can't get it to work. 
The error I get is: Bad search filter.

```
if ($ldapconn) {
    echo "jep";
    echo "<br />";

    $basedn = "DC=lab,DC=kuhlmann-its,DC=local";
    $classname = "TAI2";
    $filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=OU=TAI2,OU=Accounts,OU=BBS_Students,OU=BBS,OU=EDUNET))";
    $attributes = array("givenName", "sn", "mail");
    $search = ldap_search($ldapconn, $filter, $attributes);
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $search);

}
```

This is my first time working with LDAP and Active Directory and I don't know how all the functions work. I want to know why my ldap_search() is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that sequence of parameters is incorrect.

`$search = ldap_search($ldapconn, $filter, $attributes);`

If you check official documentation, you will notice that above line should be

`$search = ldap_search($ldapconn, $basedn, $filter, $attributes);`

Refer [ldap_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php) on official php.net documentation.

Comment: When I search for how 'memberof' is used it requires an =. So I wouldn't know how to do it without the =.

Comment: I understand that you need to use `=` operator. But, you have used it twice.

Comment: What would your suggestion be?

Comment: Good. Atleast, that error is resolved. Now, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742751/ldap-operations-error) for current issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help.