# ldap_search() Operations error

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I've looked at a lot of other questions about this but can't seen to find the solution for my error.

The code I use is:

```
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
$ldapconn = ldap_connect('[HOST]', 389);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_bind($ldapconn, $username, $password);

$authUser = $adldap->user()->authenticate($username, $password);
if ($authUser == true) {
    echo "jep";
    echo "<br />";

    $basedn     =   "DC=lab,DC=kuhlmann-its,DC=local";
    $classname  =   "TAI2";
    $filter     =   "(memberOf=OU=" . $classname . ",OU=Accounts,OU=BBS_Students,OU=BBS,OU=EDUNET,DC=lab,DC=kuhlmann-its,DC=local)";
    $attributes =   array("cn");
    $search     =   ldap_search($ldapconn, $basedn, $filter, $attributes);
    $info       =   ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $search);
```

This is my first time working with LDAP and Active Directory and I don't know how all the functions work. I want to know why my ldap_search() is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide the full error message. Also there are pleny of ldap related operations error resources on the site already. Which of them have you checked and why didn't they work for you? You should make that clear in the question so that as you're new to ldap the problem is more clear for other users here on stackoverflow and for better answers.

Comment: The answers of the other resources are about the right of the user and ldap_set_options, which I all checked and I know that they work. But even though I checked all the answers that I found it still gives me the same error.

Comment: And which ldap function triggers the error in your example? ldap_search? (Might have overlooked that earlier).

Comment: I think it's the ldap_search function. '

Comment: What the `user()->authenticate` function is for after doing a `ldapbind` ? Did you check the return values of the 2 functions `ldap_connect` and `ldap_bind`?

Comment: Most likely the username is not allowed to search. I know it sounds redundant, check if it's written correctly, it might be different to the username you expect, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19258443/367456

Comment: And the warning should contain the function name that caused the error. With error messages it is best you add them in full to your question (you can shorten the file path)

Comment: Only Guessing as you still have not provided the "error" OU=" . $classname . " looks very suspicious as "OUs" in Microsoft Active Directory typically do NOT have memberOF values.

Comment: @jwilleke The filter `memberOf=ou=...` means to look for users which are member of the `"ou=..."` which is a perfectly valid LDAP filter in this case

Comment: @esteban: I disagree and so do others. There is no MemberOf "You cannot filter on OU membership, but you can filter on group membership. . ..
Richard Mueller - MVP Directory Services" https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ff824e31-a945-4d97-929c-e497c87ac6bc/ldapquery-all-users-ine-one-ou?forum=winserverDS

Comment: @jwilleke My bad, I have to admit that I did not read your comment till the end. It is strange for AD that there would be member in an OU. Not that the filter has a wrong syntax but there would be no member in an Active Directory OU. thx for pointing it out